# How to customize Telegram's getupdates URL

Tags: url, telegram, telegram-bot, telegram-webhook, telegram-api

I try to use Telegram's getupdates URL to get updates from telegram.
For example, the URL below shows the details of the last message

URL:

```
    https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/getupdates?offset=-1
```

Response:

```
{"ok":true,"result":[{"update_id":22222222,
"channel_post":{"message_id":200,"sender_chat":{"id":-1000,"title":"Channel","username":"xxx","type":"channel"},"chat":{"id":-1000,"title":"xxx","username":"xxx","type":"channel"},"date":1111111,"text":"Hello world"}}]}
```

But, I want to receive only the **"text"** parameter as the response

```
    Hello world
```

So what strings should I add to the end of the url so that I can filter the text parameter in the server response?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is not possible.

The [`getUpdates()`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getupdates) route will always return an array of [update objects](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#update), there's no way to change that for now.

You should write some custom code to reduce the objects to just the desired fields.

---

Based on [OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74977977/how-to-customize-telegrams-getupdates-url/74983661?noredirect=1#comment132342106_74983661), the 'custom code' could look like this:

```js
// Data from getUpdates, containing a single example message
const data = {
    "ok": true,
    "result": [
        {
            "update_id": 1234567,
            "message": {
                "message_id": 752,
                "from": { "id": 12122121, "is_bot": false, "first_name": "Me", "last_name": "&", "username": "&&&&", "language_code": "en" },
                "chat": { "id": -1041255, "title": "Some group", "type": "supergroup" },
                "date": 1579999999,
                "text": "Hi!"
            }
        }
    ]
};
// Get Message Text
const messageText = data.result[0].message.text;
console.log(messageText);
```

Comment: So how can I get it as a variable? Can you send the sample code?

Comment: What language are you using to call `getUpdates`?

Comment: I want to use it in a js node

Comment: I"ve updated my answer with a JS example.